# New directory with size assigned

Tags: linux, unix

I need to create a new directory under /opt/HP, lets say /opt/HP/bits, can i assign some size to this directory,if yes can u tell how can i assign 8GB to this directory (G is GB in linux right)? Currently it shows as /dev/mapper/APPVG-hp   20G  173M   19G   1% /opt/HP.
As I need to copy 6GB bits to it., or is it not required to assign a size to it.
Could you please help, Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're using some quota system the only limiter is the free space on the volume the directory is on.

Answer (score 0):

Directories just map names to inodes (files), there can be many names pointing to the same file. So it really makes no sense to talk about the "space in the directory", and you can't limit it either.

What you *can* do is to create a new filesystem, and mount that one on the directory. Or assign quotas to the user.